# Why did Le Chiffre need the password from Bond?

Tags: plot-explanation, james-bond, casino-royale

If Vesper Lynd was working with Le Chiffre in *Casino Royale*, why did he have to force Bond for the password when she could have stolen the money and given it to Le Chiffre anyway?

Answer (score 21):

Vesper is not working *with* Le Chiffre, though they are working for the same employer. Le Chiffre is in deep with Quantum following the loss of the warlord's money and needs the winnings to cover his debts. Vesper is there to sabotage Bond's chances, because Quantum has leverage over her. She has no loyalty to Le Chiffre, as seen by the second deal she cuts, to save Bond while he is being tortured. Mr. White of Quantum intervenes and eliminates Le Chiffre because the money is Quantum's goal, regardless of how they get it. Le Chiffre is expendable to them.

It's also important to note that Vesper does not have the password at the time of the torture, Bond reveals the password (her name) later, while he is recovering.

Comment: Minor correction - the money wasn't really Mr White's objective either when he killed Le Chiffre (and saved Bond in the process) - he says to Le Chiffre "money isn't as important to our organization as knowing who to trust" before killing him, presumably because Vesper informed him of Le Chiffre's betrayal.  The money was definitely still his price for sparing Bond in addition, but killing Le Chiffre at that point was strictly in retaliation for his betrayal of Quantum