# Why does Vesper save 007 from poison?

Tags: james-bond, casino-royale

In *Casino Royale* (2006), we know Vesper worked for Le Chiffre, so she needs 007 to lose and Le Chiffre to win the tournament. Le Chiffre decides to poison 007 so he has better odds of winning. But for some reason Vesper goes out of her way to save 007's life. Did she really at that point already fell in love with him? Or are we supposed to think that she is a naive person who hoped that nobody needs to get hurt in order to save her boyfriend?

Comment: [She wasn't working for Le Chiffre](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/92313/7969)

Answer (score 2):

Vesper never worked for Le Chiffre, she worked for Mr White.  And she only worked for him because he blackmailed her, by threatening to kill her lover.  And this happened only after the poker tournament had finished.

So, she saved Bond's life because they  were on the same side at the time.

Comment: *"this happened only after the poker tournament had finished"* - That, however, is not quite accurate, I think. In any case, it's implied that she revealed Bond's discovery of Le Chiffre's tell to the latter (or anyone related to Le Chiffre), it certainly wasn't Mathis. I strongly doubt the whole blackmailing/threatening thing started only after the tournament, especially since her boyfriend worked for Quantum anyway and it was all planned long ahead. Why use that asset only after you've already lost?